Unit testing a factory with dependencies
I have been implementing unit tests and trying to increase coverage on our codebase.
I have limited experience with unit testing and so am learning a lot of it from scratch.
The project is a .NET 8 worker service - I am using xUnit, FakeItEasy and FluentAssertions.
I have a Factory object that is creating concrete classes based on a string that is passed in.  The issue is that it is using the GetRequiredService method to get it and that is failing because it is trying to use faked objects for the service provider.  Then I tried instantiating the service provider but then I needed to instantiate this other class or another and it turned into instead of faking classes I was then trying to add to the service builder each type but then when it was erroring because it couldn't use the dbcontext object in my repo object I knew I had gone off the rails.
Help!
Unit test code:
   private readonly IWatchdogWorkerFactory _workerFactory;
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
   private readonly ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory> _logger;

   public WatchdogWorkerFactoryTests()
   {
       _logger = A.Fake<ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory>>();
       _serviceProvider = A.Fake<IServiceProvider>();

       //SUT - System Under Test
       _workerFactory = new WatchdogWorkerFactory(_serviceProvider, _logger);
   }

   [Fact]
   public void WatchdogWorkerFactory_CreateDataLoadWorker()
   {
       //Triple A
       var dataLoadWorker = A.Fake<IWatchdogWorker>();

       //Arrange - go get variables, classes, functions needed to run test
       var services = new ServiceCollection();
       // Add IAppState, ILoggerAdapater, and other services
       services.AddSingleton<DataLoadWorker>();
       services.AddSingleton<DomoWorkbenchWorker>();

       // Create the service provider instance
       var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

       //Act - do some operation
       var result = _workerFactory.CreateWorker("dataload");

       //Assert - verify result
       result.Should().BeSameAs(dataLoadWorker);
   }
    .....

I think the assert should probably be checking the type so open to suggestion there.
Below is the factory object
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory> _logger;

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public WatchdogWorkerFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IWatchdogWorker CreateWorker(string watchdogType)
    {
        switch (watchdogType.ToLower())
        {
            case "dataload":
                return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataLoadWorker>();
            case "domoworkbench":
                return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DomoWorkbenchWorker>();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown watchdog type: {watchdogType}");
        }
    }
}

This is the error if I just leave the fakes and what not:

Update:
Here is the calling code:
                    var worker = _watchdogWorkerFactory.CreateWorker(watchdog.WatchdogType);
            var task = Task.Run(() => worker.Process(_taskCancellation, watchdog), stoppingToken);

The IWatchdogWorker interface:
        public interface IWatchdogWorker
        {
              Task<bool> Process(CancellationToken cancelToken, 
              WatchdogDTO watchdogItem);
        }

Updated error from trying to fake the call to CreateWorker:


Hey. It doesn't seem like you're happy with any of the answers to your question. If you think a more interactive approach may help, please do drop into the FakeIteasy gitter room or GitHub discussions

You kind of have a lot going on here. The main problems I see are confusion over how your SUT interacts with the faked collaborators. You make some good collaborators and provide them to your SUT, but then go off and make a concrete service provider that (as far as I can tell) is unrelated to your SUT.
Also your fake collaborators are largely unconfigured. I've taken your sample code, added enough to make it compile, and chopped out what I thought was irrelevant to your test.
In the end, we

create some fakes,
provide them to the SUT,
configure the fake to return desired values,
exercise the SUT, and
assess the results

I hope this is useful. I'm happy to discuss if you want.
namespace fiequestions;

using FakeItEasy;
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; // late addition

public interface ILogger<T>
{
}

public interface IWatchdogWorker
{
}

public class ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public interface IWatchdogWorkerFactory
{
    IWatchdogWorker CreateWorker(string watchdogType);
}

public class DataLoadWorker: IWatchdogWorker
{}

public class DomoWorkbenchWorker: IWatchdogWorker
{}

public class WatchdogWorkerFactoryTests
{
    public class WatchdogWorkerFactory: IWatchdogWorkerFactory
    {

        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory> _logger;

        [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public WatchdogWorkerFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory> logger)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IWatchdogWorker CreateWorker(string watchdogType)
        {
            switch (watchdogType.ToLower())
            {
                case "dataload":
                    return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataLoadWorker>();
                case "domoworkbench":
                    return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DomoWorkbenchWorker>();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown watchdog type: {watchdogType}");
            }
        }
    }

   private readonly IWatchdogWorkerFactory _workerFactory;
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
   private readonly ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory> _logger;

   public WatchdogWorkerFactoryTests()
   {
       _logger = A.Fake<ILogger<WatchdogWorkerFactory>>();
       _serviceProvider = A.Fake<IServiceProvider>();

       //SUT - System Under Test
       _workerFactory = new WatchdogWorkerFactory(_serviceProvider, _logger);
   }

   [Fact]
   public void WatchdogWorkerFactory_CreateDataLoadWorker()
   {
       //Triple A
       //Arrange

       // as pointed out to me in sidechat, GetRequiredService is
       // an extension method, so we have to fake the method that's
       // ultimately called on the IServiceProvider
       var dataLoadWorker = A.Fake<DataLoadWorker>();
       A.CallTo(() => _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DataLoadWorker))).Returns(dataLoadWorker);

       //Act - do some operation
       var result = _workerFactory.CreateWorker("dataload");

       //Assert - verify result
       result.Should().BeSameAs(dataLoadWorker);
   }
}


While this compiles - it breaks at runtime because of the faking of the data load worker
Screenshot attached to main post

I'm not sure what to tell you. The code in my answer above actually didn't compile. It was missing using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;, since added.
For me it passes.

I think that you are trying to test the framework. Don't do that.
You can always build your factory like:
  public IWatchdogWorker CreateWorker(string watchdogType)
  {
    Type t = Type.GetType(watchdogType);
    return _services.GetRequiredService(t);
  }

Or just pass a Type directly to the method instead of a string. Any that would make your factory unneccessary, because you could just use IServiceProvider directly (you could inject IServiceProvider into the service that needs to use WatchdogWorker).
So your problem is testing problem - you just test a framework after all.
Another problem is that you are creating fake for IWatchdogWorker:
var dataLoadWorker = A.Fake<IWatchdogWorker>();
and then want it to be the same as the one returned from factory:
result.Should().BeSameAs(dataLoadWorker);
Those are two completely different things. Your dataLoadWorker is just a mock class and result is a real class. So those are two different classes, not only objects.
But if you registered your implementation as A.Fake<IWatchdogWorker> then it is also a compeletely different object.
What you could do it just:
var dataLoadWorker = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService("dataload")
and then this one could be compared to the one returned by the factory - but you still are testing the framework.

I updated my original post with code for the interface and the code that calls the create factory worker.
I was thinking I would compare the types between what is returned from the factory and the type I am expecting with the unit test.
I figured there may be an anti-pattern here but I was following the factory pattern which I think is correct - I have one interface with a process method - and the factory gets the concrete class based on the parameter.  Otherwise I would need some if statements in my main code block that would make it uglier.

Ultimately I am trying to unit test that the correct type of object comes back - I don't want to just pass a type because again - I would need the if logic in the main calling code - the string being passed in comes from a database row.
